# How do you illuminate your sukkah?

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkot, sukkah, lighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Advice for Lighting in a Sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/advice-for-lighting-in-a-sukkah)

How do you keep your sukkah well-lit?